# Can we wrap Log4Net Log Statement in a try/catch?

Tags: log4net

Does it make sense to wrap logging statement in a try/catch?
I am using Log4net as:

```
 LogManager.GetLogger(type).Debug(message, exception)
```

To prevent Log4net from throwing an exception(I know its fail-stop,still) or to prevent the application from  crashing in case the logging logic throws an exception, does it make sense to wrap the call in a try/catch?

```
try{
LogManager.GetLogger(type).Debug(message, exception)
} catch(Exception e){//Some Logic Here}
```

Also, looking for recommendations on what should happen in catch clause in case an excpetion is caught.

Comment: log4net does not throw exceptions. As the documentation says _"If for any reason, log4net throws an uncaught exception (except for ArgumentException and ArgumentNullException which may be thrown), please send an email to the log4net-user@logging.apache.org mailing list. **Uncaught exceptions are handled as serious bugs requiring immediate attention.**"_

Answer (score 2):

Log4net will never throw an exception by design. Log4Net is designed to not interact with your program flow. Things that can go wrong are bugs in how you format your parameters. But log4net it self should never throw an exception.

Log4net FAQ:

> Is log4net a reliable logging system? No. log4net is not reliable. It
>   is a best-effort and fail-stop logging system.  By fail-stop, we mean
>   that log4net will not throw unexpected exceptions at run-time
>   potentially causing your application to crash. If for any reason,
>   log4net throws an uncaught exception, please send an email to the
>   log4net-users@lists.sourceforge.net mailing list. Uncaught exceptions
>   are handled as serious bugs requiring immediate attention.